# Converting ubx file to RINEX; not obtaining .nav files, why?

Tags: gps

I'm trying to convert `.ubx` file to RINEX `.obs` and `.nav` files with RTKLIB.
But I found that sometime only `.obs` file can be generated while `.nav` can not.

What kind of data do I need in `.ubx` to generate `.nav` file?
Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: It worked, but not perfectly. Basically, the .obs file is generated from the raw data(called RXM-RAW) and the .nav file is from the ephemeris(RXM-EPH and RXM-SFRB), so if you have these data in your .ubx file, the problem should be solved. However, in my experience, the generated files will sometime only contain invalid records like 0.00000000 even you have both raw and ephemeris.

Comment: Did you succeed in doing a post processing correction? What was the final accuracy (deviation from real position) you got?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to **enable both messagetypes RXM-RAW and RXM-SFRB**.

To make sure the conversion from .ubx-Files works properly you should **disable every other messages (use u-center)**. Sometimes RTKLIB does not work well with mixed files. UBX files are binary files and should not be filled up with NMEA-Messages.

My LEA-4t runs on a RasperryPi with a Python-Script I developed. It is a Statemachine that only puts out the RXM-Messages that are needed. It works well for me.

Comment: I was missing the SRFB messages, thanks a lot +1. Worth noticing that some gps parts use RAWX and SFRBX message types instead (like the ZED-F9P), one should check which one is supported by the device one is using.

Answer (score 1):

To create suitable RINEX you need a Ublox chip with enabled "RAW data option". A normal ublx chip does not have that option. But if you pay ublox probably the firmware of the chip can be updated to output that RAW messages.

These RAW messages contains the "original" data of the satellite signal.
So probaly your ubx file does not contain that raw messages.

See also ublox binary protocoll specification on ublox web page.
There are the RAW messages decribed

Comment: Thank your for answering my question.
My ublox chip can output raw data(labeled as RXM-RAW in u-center).
But the .ubx file I got from it can only be converted into .obs file using RTKLIB.
I think something is wrong in the configuration part.

Comment: Are you sure that the ubx file contains the raw data messages? (If enabled in u-center it shoudl work). More I don't know. Is RTK Lib Open Source? Could you update your question to post a link to RTK Lib project web page? You could debug RTK Lib code to see why the file is not created.

Comment: I have the exam same problem. I enabled both RXM-RAW and RXM-SFRB messages but I only get observation file (.obs) but no nav file from ublox binary file. I used both version 2.4.2 and 2.4.3 versions of RTKLIB software.